# Create a PDF from retrieved data, and return the PDF to the browser WITHOUT a third party tool?

Tags: c#, pdf, model-view-controller

Ok, what I'm trying to do is take information from a database, and convert that info to a PDF, **without** using a third-party tool. I've googled this, and tried several different incarnations. The *closest* I've gotten is this:

```
[HttpGet, ActionName("getthepdf")]
public void CreateTheFile()
{
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();

    string myString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac eleifend nunc, eget consequat arcu.";

    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);

    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=testdoc_1.pdf");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myString.Length.ToString());

    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
}
```

Which doesn't work over https. It "creates" a PDF (or, probably more correctly, a file with a .pdf extension), but whenever I try to open it in Adobe Reader, I get:

Adobe Reader could not open 'testdoc_1.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged...

When I try to open it in a browser (Chrome, in this case), I get "Failed to load PDF Document".

What's odd (and this could just be a function of the software) is that if I change the desired file type to .doc, it puts unformatted text in a .doc file that I can actually open with word.

The company wants a PDF that the end user can print or save to their local machine, so I'm trying to figure out how to give them what they want. If this isn't possible, I may have to see if I can get them to settle for a .doc file.

At this point, it doesn't have to look ***pretty***, it just has to work.

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your sample code spits back plain text and hints the filename ends with .PDF - this has nothing to do with actually *creating* a PDF, if you used `testdoc_1.jpg` you would not expect to get an image.  What is the issue with using a proven PDF library?

Comment: It is not always good to re-inventing the wheel. I agree with @Stephen.

Comment: I'd advise maybe looking into seeing if the data can't be exported into a different format, if you can't use any 3rd party tools, as you'll be spending (at best) several weeks trying to implement the PDF specification, even partially, from scratch without use of a 3rd party tool.  I'd be curious as to why 3rd party tools aren't allowed?  For creation of most types of files, you'll need to have some reliance on 3rd party tools, as most file formats are rather complex (outside of html, xml, plain text, and csv being the only common ones that come to mind).

Comment: @AlexK.@user2366842 non-use of a third-party tool is a company requirement. Their decision, not mine. Though I did just talk to someone at my workplace regarding this, and they told me a ".doc" is fine. Yes, I know now that it's sent as text, but if they can open it in Word (or an equivalent) then I think I'll be fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a pdf, it has to conform to the PDF specification (available for a fee from ISO: [Pdf Specification](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=51502)). It's not just plain text with a pdf extension. You could of course write your own implementation, if you absolutely cannot use a third party library, but I would strongly advice against that. It's a lot of work, and others have done it probably better than you could.

Answer (score 0):

I no longer need assistance with this. My lead has now said I can use iTextSharp. This question can now be considered closed.